# Unable to click on hyperlink

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am writing selenium code to click Edit a group from a list of groupnames.I am parsing a groupname and trying to click Edit link corresponding to that groupName.

I am able to find the Edit link using xpath and seems to be correct when I check that with xpath checker. However when i run the code, it throws exception that it didnt find the element.

Need help. Here is my code.

```
Xpath:

xpath=//div [@class='datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-c1-adminGroupName')][(text()='--VARIABLE--')]/parent::td/preceding-sibling::td[2]/div/a[1]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the actual Java code (esp. since you tagged only with Java)?

Comment: Thanks paul,here you go                                                     session().findElement(getElement("Administration", "EditLink").getBy("--VARIABLE--",groupName)).click();

Comment: please give us the relevant html code...

Comment: <tr id="datagrid-row-r1-2-3" class="datagrid-row datagrid-row-selected" datagrid-row-index="3" style="height: 25px;">
<td field="action">
<div class="datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-c1-action" style="height:auto;">
<a onclick="javascript:openWindow('/mnet/view/adminGroups/edit.mc?AdminGroupID=5')" href="#">Edit</a>
<a onclick="javascript:changeGroupState(5,true)" href="#">Disable</a>
</div>
</td>
<td field="deleted">
<div class="datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-c1-deleted" style="height:auto;">
<div style="text-align:center">
</div>
</td>---(a)

Comment: (a)-------<td field="adminGroupName">
<div class="datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-c1-adminGroupName" style="height:auto;">Processor Risk Analyst</div>
</td>
<td field="privileges">
<div class="datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-c1-privileges" style="height:auto;">
<label title="Monthly, Weekly, View Generated Report, View Scheduled Report, Create Report">Monthly, Weekly, View Generated Report, View Scheduled Report, Create Report</label>
</div>
</td>

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with any sort of browser based scraping the applications are not good at clicking xpath's very deep into the dom tree or with extremely long class names tacked on to each other.  I would take the approach of using a shorter xpath.   If you know what the text is and if it's unique enough, can you change your xpath to something like this?

```
//a[text()="edit"]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have a list of usernames with edit options for all. I want to click Edit link of selected username.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the solution for my question. I had to get the xpath of text corresponding to the hyperlink and navigate to the hyperlink and use get attribute for same. This worked.

session().findElement(getElement(by.xpath).getAttribute("class"));

Thank you for your time.